# DllImport - DllNotFoundException with android .so

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, shared-libraries

It's the first time I try to create a library c++ for Android/iOS.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 - Xamarin.

First I created a project : Visual C++ -> Cross Platform -> Shared Library. In the hared library, I created 2 files.

SayHello.h :

```
#pragma once
#include <string.h>

class SayHello {
public:
    SayHello();
    ~SayHello();
    static char* Hello();
};
```

SayHello.cpp :

```
#include "SayHello.h"
extern "C"
{
    SayHello::SayHello(){}

    SayHello::~SayHello(){}

    char * SayHello::Hello()
    {
        return "Hello !";
    }
}
```

Then I generated a file `libSayHello.so` and created a project Android with xamarin to try to call the function hello.
There is my MainActivity.cs :

```
[DllImport("libSayHello.so")]
static extern String Hello();

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    // I paste only my added code :
    String hello = Hello();
    Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, hello, ToastLength.Long);
}
```

I did all steps in [this tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/), but I have an exception :

> System.DllNotFoundException: libSayHello.so

I searched for this, but I must be so noob cause I did not find anything. How should I use my `libSayHello.so` ?

**EDIT:**

There is my `libSayHello.so` seen with 7zip:

[image]

And my project :

[image]

Comment: Did `libSayHello.so` make it into the `apk` file?  It's just a zip file so you can rename it and use any zipfile manager to look at it's contents.  Also the Android loader does not do cascade loading so if your shared library depends on any other libraries (including runtime support libraries) you have to load them 1st.

Comment: I looked into the .so but I don't know what i'm looking for. I'll edit my question with picture.

Comment: @A.Pissicat, please, tell us do you see reference to your shared lib in solution explorer? Look it here: Solution 'SayHello' -> test -> References. Do you see there 'SayHello'?

Comment: @Sheikh there is no reference cause I try to use it with the .so file. I'try to add the reference to check, I still have the error.

Comment: So do you mean that it will be like third-party library? And you will just include it in another Xamarin.Android? Take a look at this [xamarin guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/). I will also try to do it in such way and report you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will be [the best sample](https://github.com/lothrop/XamarinNative) for you.

This all works according to the following scheme:

1. Android supports 7 CPU architectures.

   But Xamarin supports 5 of them. So in the settings of your Xamarin.Android project check which architectures you will support:

   `[Xamarin.Droid.project]->[Properties]->[Android Options]->[Advanced]->[Supported architectures]`

[image]

Check which archs are necessary for your project. According to this your shared library should be compiled for these archs. And you should put your shared libraries in Xamarin.Droid.project's folder lib:

[image]

2. To see them in Solution Explorer you should mention them in your Xamarin.Android project's **.CSPROJ**.

   Add there next item groups:

   `<ItemGroup>
       <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="lib\{ARCH}\libCLib.so">
          <Abi>{ARCH}</Abi>
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       </AndroidNativeLibrary>
    </ItemGroup>`

   {ARCH} could be next: **armeabi**, **armeabi-v7a**, **arm64-v8a**, **x86**, **x86_64**.
3. Now you can put *DllImport* in your code:

   ```
   [DllImport("libCLib", EntryPoint = "clib_add")]
   public static extern int Add(int left, int right);
   ```

   I think you have to tell about entry point, because i had runtime errors without this statement **System.EntryPointNotFoundException**.

   And don't forget to add next in your code:

   `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: I've try your solution, I have no more `DllNotFoundException` but now I have the `EntryPointNotFoundException`. I've try by copying the function `clib_add` from example to my project and call it exactly like CTest project but it did not work. I don't understand what i'm missing.

Comment: I just moved my `extern "C"` from the .Shared project to the .Android project and now it's working !
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm the library is put in "/lib/{arch}/" folder.
2. Try [DllImport("SayHello")]. the engine may add "lib" and ".so" automatically.

Comment: My library has been generated for ARM. I have try to put in folder `lib/ARM` and call it with DllImport but I still have error. I've try with/without entire path, with/without extension but nothing work. I checked, I run the android project with Debug/ARM